# Options for establishing a secure TCP connection to an IoT edge device over the internet

Tags: tcp

I have an IoT edge device which is currently configured as a TCP server; the device gathers and processes some data, and then passes it to the connected clients. This works as intended when the server and client(s) are on the same network.

However, the above represents only one of four possible use cases:

1. Edge device and client(s) on the same network (as per above).
2. Edge device connected to internet via modem/router, with client(s) on a different network.
3. Edge device connected to internet via mobile phone hotspot, with client(s) on a different network.
4. Edge device connected to internet via 4G dongle, with client(s) on a different network.

In case 2 above, I understand how the process in case 1 can be applied, by establishing port forwarding on the edge device's connected modem/router and using the network's public IP address. However, from my understanding, port forwarding is unavailable (for all intents and purposes) when using a mobile hotspot connection. Similarly, 4G dongle carriers don't (typically) provide a public IP address, so routing a TCP connection to the edge device server wouldn't work in this case either.

What options are available which would allow for client-server TCP connections for all four use cases? For additional context and consideration, the TCP data will also need to be secured/obfuscated. Additionally, the data is time-sensitive, so ensuring minimal delay between transmission of the data from the server and reception of the data by the client(s) is paramount.

Comment: Please specify "minimal delay" - milliseconds? Tenths of seconds? Seconds?

Comment: Ideally less than the 20ms, but I would accept up to 500ms if there were no lower latency alternative.

Comment: "less than 20 ms" excludes *any* transfer across WAN. 500 ms is certainly possible across WAN and cloud.

Comment: Ok great, I can work with that. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an intermediary rendezvous server in the cloud, and all devices connect to it.

There are several options for encryption, but we’d need more details before recommending something.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I've since done some further reading on this possibility. The transmission/reception of the data is time sensitive (a consideration which I left out of the original post, my apologies); so a rendezvous/relay server approach probably isn't suitable. A direct peer-to-peer connection would definitely be preferable.

Comment: @jars121 You cannot connect into a private network without port forwarding/destination NAT. A rendezvous server ("cloud") is your only option.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. In the hours since my comment I've done further research and come to this conclusion. Would you recommend a STUN/TURN implementation? From my understanding, this would facilitate all use cases, and only resort to relaying the data via the TURN server when P2P is not possible.

Comment: STUN might work in some networks, but only a fraction without prior configuration.

Comment: It should work on a network where the required port has been forwarded on the network's router? I.e. STUN provides the public IP of the network, and the forwarding provides the routing to the device.

Comment: @jars121 how much delay can you accept?  You mention 500 mS in your question. That’s certainly doable.

Comment: @jars121 STUN is a generic way to set up port forwarding (as far as permitted by policies). If you've got port forwarding you don't need STUN.